# Dynamic menu items with dynamic shortcut keys using c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, menu, keyboard-shortcuts

My question about c# wpf

I am creating one windows application using c# WPF, I am creating menus on main window using menu control from code behind (c#) menu's data coming from database. One more table in my database for keyboard short cut key data. So, I want to assign that short cut key value in respective menu item. How can we achieve that?

In short how to assign dynamic short cut key values to dynamic menu items?

For example,
Menu is  _Transactions
Menu Item is _Sales
Sub Menu Item is _Add
Sub Menu Item is _Display

Short Cut key data from database
KeyValue for Transaction Menu is Alt + T

Sample code is...

```
try
        {
            menuContainer.Children.Clear();
            System.Windows.Controls.Menu topMenu = new 
System.Windows.Controls.Menu();
            DataTable dtMainMenu = Global.DatabaseMethod.GetMenuData();
            DataTable dtSubMenu = null;
            DataTable dtChildMenu = null;
            DataTable dtSubChildMenu = null;
            if (dtMainMenu != null && dtMainMenu.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MenuItem parentMenuItem = null;
                MenuItem subMenuItem = null;
                MenuItem childMenuItem = null;
                MenuItem subchildMenuItem = null;
                DataRow[] dataRow = null;
                dtMainMenu.DefaultView.Sort = "SequenceNumber ASC";
                dtMainMenu = dtMainMenu.DefaultView.ToTable();
                foreach (DataRow parentMenuRow in dtMainMenu.Rows)
                {
                    parentMenuItem = new MenuItem();
                    parentMenuItem.Tag = 
parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.Slug].ToString() + "~" + 
parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID].ToString();
                    parentMenuItem.Header = 
parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.MenuName].ToString();
                    dataRow = Global.dtUserRole.Select("((MenuId='" + 
Convert.ToInt32(parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID]) + "' AND 
SubMenuId=0 AND ChildMenuId=0) OR (MenuId='" + 
Convert.ToInt32(parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID]) + "'))");
                    parentMenuItem.PreviewMouseDown += 
MenuItem_PreviewMouseDown;
                    parentMenuItem.PreviewKeyDown += 
MenuItem_PreviewKeyDown;
                    if (dataRow.Length > 0)
                    {
                        topMenu.Items.Add(parentMenuItem);
                        if (!Convert.ToBoolean(dataRow[dataRow.Length - 
1][ColumnNameConstants.VisibleRole]))
                        {
                            parentMenuItem.Visibility = 
Visibility.Collapsed;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        topMenu.Items.Add(parentMenuItem);
                        parentMenuItem.Visibility = 
Visibility.Collapsed;
                    }
                }
                topMenu.Background = Brushes.Transparent;
                topMenu.Foreground = Brushes.White;
                topMenu.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
                menuContainer.Children.Add(topMenu);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
         
        }
```

Comment: Can you show us some code that creates these menu items? Might be easier for us then to tell exactly what you're supposed to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should get you a bit closer.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApp11.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp11"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
        <Grid>
            <Menu x:Name="mainmenu" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Grid>
    </Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace WpfApp11
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, ICommand
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem filemenu = new MenuItem();
            filemenu.Header = "_File";

            MenuItem menuitem1 = new MenuItem();
            menuitem1.Header = "Item _1";
            menuitem1.InputGestureText = "Ctrl+A";
            //menuitem1.Click += menuitem_Click;
            //menuitem1.Tag = "slug1~id1"; //parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.Slug].ToString() + "~" + parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID].ToString();
            menuitem1.CommandParameter = "slug1~id1"; //parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.Slug].ToString() + "~" + parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID].ToString();
            menuitem1.Command = this;

            MenuItem menuitem2 = new MenuItem();
            menuitem2.Header = "Item _2";
            menuitem2.InputGestureText = "Ctrl+B";
            //menuitem2.Click += menuitem_Click;
            //menuitem2.Tag = "slug2~id2"; //parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.Slug].ToString() + "~" + parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID].ToString();
            menuitem2.CommandParameter = "slug2~id2"; //parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.Slug].ToString() + "~" + parentMenuRow[ColumnNameConstants.ID].ToString();
            menuitem2.Command = this;

            filemenu.Items.Add(menuitem1);
            filemenu.Items.Add(menuitem2);

            mainmenu.Items.Add(filemenu);

            this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(this, Key.A, ModifierKeys.Control) { Command = this, CommandParameter = "slug1~id1" });
            this.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(this, Key.B, ModifierKeys.Control) { Command = this, CommandParameter = "slug2~id2" });
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void menuitem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MenuItem menu = sender as MenuItem;

            if (menu != null)
            { 
                MessageBox.Show(menu.Tag as string);

                e.Handled = true;
            }
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }

        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            string item = parameter as string;

            if (item == "slug1~id1")
            { 
                // Decide if command should be enabled of not

                return true;
            }

            if (item == "slug2~id2")
            {
                // Decide if command should be enabled of not

                return true;
            }

            return false;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            ExecuteItem(parameter);
        }

        //----------------------------------------------------------------------

        private void ExecuteItem(object parameter)
        {
            string item = parameter as string;

            if (item != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(item);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply CSmith

Comment: I can't implement ICommand interface because many code contains "this" so it is raising issues. Please help me to fix this.

Comment: error CS0263: Partial declarations of 'MainWindow' must not specify different base classes

Comment: Are you using NET Framework 4, or using NET 5 or 6? I used NET Framework. All you need to do is implement ICommand on something. The "this" references, are to access the "Window" object, so that the inputbindings can be added for the key shortcuts, and to refer to the "command". Don't have "two" MainWindow partial classes with different base classes....don't just copy what I did and put in your source...as you probably already have a MainWindow class somewhere.

Comment: It's working fine now. Thank you CSmith.

Comment: If the answer solves your question, then please accept the answer, to let people know, thanks.